# How to swap nibbles in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How to swap the nibble bit positions of a number?

For example: 534, convert it into binary, the rightmost 4 bits has to be interchanged with the leftmost 4 bits and then make a new number with that.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you state the problem more clearly?  534 doesn't fit into 8 bits - do you mean a 16 bit number, if so which nibbles do you want to swap?

Comment: just consider only about 8 bits! :)

Comment: This is why you should learn binary and hex before learning programming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the fact that hexadecimal `0xf` covers exactly four bits. There are four nibbles in a 16-bit number. The masks for the nibbles are `0xf000`, `0xf00`, `0xf0`, and `0xf`. Then start masking, shifting and bitwise OR-ing.

Comment: Actually, what is the difference between 0x0F and 0xF0 ?

Comment: `0xf0` is 240 in decimal, while `0x0f` is 15.

Comment: I saw this example from one site..
`unsigned char c= 0x34;
temp1 = c & 0x0F;
temp2 = c & 0xF0;
temp1=temp1 << 4;
temp2=temp2 >> 4; 
return(temp2|temp1);`

What does that mean?

Comment: It means: assign the value 0x34 to c; store the bottom 4 bits of c in temp1; store the top 4 bits of c in temp2; shift the bits in temp1 4 places left; shift the bits in temp2 4 places right; OR temp2 and temp1 together to create an 8-bit value.  Do some Google searching for bit manipulation and it will make more sense.

Answer (score 5):

[Sean Anderson's bit twiddling guide](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) has the following:

```
// swap nibbles ... 
v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4);
```

under the entry for [Reverse an N-bit quantity in parallel in 5 * lg(N) operations](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel).

Comment: I saw this example from one site.. `unsigned char c= 0x34; temp1 = c & 0x0F; temp2 = c & 0xF0; temp1=temp1 << 4; temp2=temp2 >> 4; return(temp2|temp1);` What does that mean?

Comment: You forgot to make sure the bitmask size is correct with sizeof, remembering that there are no size guarantees in C

Answer (score 4):

1)

```
y = ((x >> 4) & 0x0f) | ((x << 4) & 0xf0);
```

2)

```
unsigned char swap_nibbles(unsigned char c)
{
     unsigned char temp1, temp2;

     temp1 = c & 0x0F;
     temp2 = c & 0xF0;
     temp1=temp1 << 4;
     temp2=temp2 >> 4;

     return(temp2|temp1); //adding the bits
}
```

3)

```
unsigned char nibbleSwap(unsigned char a)
{
    return (a<<4) | (a>>4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//program to swap nibbles from 32 bit number swap
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
 uint32_t n = 0x10203040;
 uint32_t swaped_no=0;
 int data;
 char shift = 0;
 for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
 {
  data= n>>shift;
  data = (((data & 0x0F)<<4) | ((data & 0xF0)>>4));
  swaped_no = swaped_no | (data<<shift);
  shift=shift+8;
 }
 printf("swapped no 0x%08x",swaped_no);
}
```

swapped no 0x01020304

Comment: would you mind fixing the code a bit with consistent indentation and having main actually return something? the code displayed in the site should be high quality and pass a code review cleanly if possible.